# IIS 500.19, bizarre error

Tags: iis, iis-7

I'm getting a 500.19 error in IIS7 for a site I've set up locally. I've given IIS_IUSRS and even Everyone full control on the directory and reinstalled ASP.NET in IIS.  I can't request any files - images etc, and I've spent so long looking for solutions and I'm not sure what else to try.

Comment: I have the exact same site running on an identical setup on another machine using subversion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The IIS7 rewrite module (or lack thereof) will cause this error if it's not installed. You won't get errors with anything mentioning the rewrite section though. You can download it at  http://www.iis.net/download/urlrewrite.

It's got me a few times before I eventually realize it's missing on a new install.

Comment: Just to add to this - I had the exact same issue, but IIS thought the module WAS installed. Uninstalling from the Control Panel and reinstalling with the Web Platform Installer fixed it.

Comment: I met the same problem,  urlrewrite install success on windows server 2012 r2 ,but failed on my dev-pc( windows 10 ).

Comment: Clearly you need a tool like Jexus Manager, https://blog.lextudio.com/jexus-manager-new-hope-to-end-oob-related-500-19-errors-193854de0d4d which provides much better error reporting and analysis.